# How to convert bytes represented as a string to the real bytes

Tags: python, string, decoding, text-decoding

Suppose we have a string that looks like this:

```
fake_bytes = "b'This is a check - \xe2\x9c\x94\xef\xb8\x8f'"
```

So this `fake_bytes` string is a text that is encoded in bytes and visually converted to string (without decoding the bytes).

The question is how to convert `fake_bytes` again to bytes without encoding its contents again to get something like that:

```
real_bytes = b'This is a check - \xe2\x9c\x94\xef\xb8\x8f'
```

The `real_bytes` is bytes with the same contents as a string and can be decoded to the original text later:

```
>>> real_bytes.decode()
check ✔️
```

Comment: Note; python bytes string can only contains ASCII characters

Comment: Do you mean you want to find another to convert str to bytes instead using ecode('utf-8')?

Comment: Yes, I`m searching for the way to convert this string to bytes without encoding its contents.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(fake_bytes)`

Comment: Or, strip the `b'...'` and encode as Latin-1. This is technically a violation of the requirement to avoid encoding, but I'm guessing you have that requirement to avoid having the encoding interfere with the interpretation somehow, which Latin-1 uniquely doesn't do.

Answer (score -1):

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58)
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> fake_bytes = "b'This is a check - \xe2\x9c\x94\xef\xb8\x8f'"
>>> x = fake_bytes.encode('utf-8')[2:-1]
>>> x
b'This is a check - \xc3\xa2\xc2\x9c\xc2\x94\xc3\xaf\xc2\xb8\xc2\x8f'
```